# Constructor not defined: .<Constructor>()

Tags: apex, batch

can anyone please help with how to resolve this error?
I am getting this error  `Constructor not defined: [GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers].<Constructor>()`
at `GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers CreatePartnerUsers = new GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers();`

global class GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers implements Database.Batchable{

```
   global Set<Id> listOfContacts = new Set<Id>();
   global String query = ''; 
   
   global GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers(Set<Id> contactsList){
     System.debug('Contacts List : ' +contactsList);
      listOfContacts= contactsList;
      query = 'select id, Email,ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c, phone, FirstName, LastName, AccountId,Account.Name, MailingStateCode, Agent_Code__c,vlocity_ins__Type__c from contact where id in :listOfContacts AND ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c != Null AND AccountId != Null';
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
     Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
     Set<Id> accSet = new Set<Id>();
     Map<String, User> userConMap = new Map<String, User>();
     Map<String, Contact> conMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
     List<User> usersToUpsert = new List<User>();
     
     system.debug('scope:'+scope);
     
     for(sobject s : scope){
          Contact con = (Contact)s;
          conMap.put(con.Id, con);
          accSet.add(con.AccountId);
     }
     System.debug('***ConMap :***' +conMap);
     System.debug('***accSet*** ' +accSet);
     for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, GA_Agency_Code__c, IsPartner FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accSet]){
         System.debug('***acc*** ' +acc);                            
         if(acc.IsPartner)
           accMap.put(acc.Id, acc); 
     }
     System.debug('***accMap***' +accMap);
    
     for(User usr : [select id, contactid,FederationIdentifier from User where contactid in : conMap.keySet() and profile.Name = 'BCBSM FSA Login']){
          userConMap.put(usr.contactId, usr);
     }
     System.debug('***userConMap***' +userConMap);
     Organization thisOrg = [SELECT InstanceName,IsSandbox,Name,NamespacePrefix,OrganizationType FROM Organization];
     Profile BCBSMFSAProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE '%BCBSM FSA Login%' Limit 1];
        for(String conId : conMap.keySet()){
          Contact con = conMap.get(conId);
          User usr = userConMap.get(conId);
          System.debug('***con***' +con);
          System.debug('***ConMapSize***'+conMap.size());
          System.debug('***usr**:'+usr);
          if(con != Null && (accMap.containsKey(con.AccountId) && accMap.get(con.AccountId) != null && accMap.get(con.AccountId).GA_Agency_Code__c != null) && string.isNotBlank(con.Email) && String.isNotBlank(con.ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c))
          {
          System.debug('***Debug Statement***');
          
          if(usr != null){
              System.debug('*UserIf*');
                User u = new User(Id = usr.Id); 
                     u.FederationIdentifier = con.Email;                       
                     u.Email=con.Email;                        
                     u.CommunityNickname = con.FirstName +' '+ con.LastName +' '+ con.Agent_Code__c; 
                     /*Nickname is updated by concatenating the full name with Agent */                        
             
                usersToUpsert.add(u);
                 
           }
           else{
               System.debug('***UserElse***');
                String buildUserNameExt = '';
                If (thisOrg.isSandbox){
                  buildUserNameExt = '.'+ thisOrg.InstanceName;
                }                            
                User PartnerUser = new User(FirstName = con.FirstName, 
                     Username = con.FirstName.deleteWhitespace()+'.'+con.LastName.deleteWhitespace()+'-'+con.Agent_Code__c+'@bcbsm.agent'+buildUserNameExt,
                     ContactId = con.Id,
                                           
                     ProfileId = BCBSMFSAProfile.Id,
                     Alias =con.FirstName.substring(0,1) + string.valueof(con.Id).substring(12,18), 
                     Email = con.Email,
                     EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                     LastName = con.LastName,
                     /*Nickname is updated from Agent Id to Contact Full Name */ 
                     CommunityNickname = con.FirstName +' '+ con.LastName +' '+ con.Agent_Code__c,                          
                     TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
                     LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                     LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                     StateCode = con.MailingStateCode,
                     FederationIdentifier = con.email,                         
                     isActive=true);
                     
                     System.debug('PartnerUser Object&&&&&&&:'+PartnerUser );
                     usersToUpsert.add(PartnerUser);
                
            
               }
           }
      }
       System.debug('***usersToUpsert***' +usersToUpsert);  
       Database.upsert(usersToUpsert);
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest

 private class GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers_Test {

  private static testMethod void insertPartnerUser(){
 {
     
      UserRole userrole = [Select Id, DeveloperName From UserRole Where DeveloperName = 
 'System_Administrator' Limit 1];
    user usr = GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.UsrRec('System 
  Administrator','testsysadm@bcbsm.com','System Administrator');
    usr.UserRoleId  = userrole.id;
    database.insert(usr);
    system.runAs(usr){
     
       //static testMethod void insertPartnerUser(){
        List<Account> listOfaccs = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> lisOfcntcts = new  List<Contact> ();
        //Inserting an account & making it as partner
        
        Account AORSRacc = GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.AccRec();
        AORSRacc.RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account - Agency').getRecordTypeId();          
        AORSRacc.GA_Agency_Code__c='89899';
        database.insert(AORSRacc);

        Account AORSRacc1 = GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.AccRec();
        AORSRacc1.RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account - Agency').getRecordTypeId();          
        AORSRacc1.GA_Agency_Code__c='89800';
        database.insert(AORSRacc1);
        listOfaccs.add(AORSRacc);
        listOfaccs.add(AORSRacc1);
      
        Contact conta =  GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.cntactRec(AORSRacc1.id);
        conta.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account - Agency').getRecordTypeId();
        conta.vlocity_ins__Type__c='Agent';   
        conta.ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c='15768';
        conta.Active__c = True;
        lisOfcntcts.add(conta);
      
        Contact conta1 =  GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.cntactRec(AORSRacc.id);
        conta1.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contact - 
  Delegate').getRecordTypeId();
        conta1.vlocity_ins__Type__c='Agent';    
        conta1.Active__c = True;
        conta1.ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c='15748';
       conta1.email= 'test1.test21@gmail.com';
        lisOfcntcts.add(conta1);  
        database.insert(lisOfcntcts); 
        
        list<user> usrLst=new list<user>();
        user hisusr = GA_OBJ_TD01_TestDataCreation.UsrRec('BCBSMTest Partner 
   User','testsalesrepmail@bcbsm.com','BCBSM Both');
        hisusr.ContactId = conta1.id;
        hisusr.IsActive = True;
        usrLst.add(hisusr);
        insert usrLst;
     
        GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers CreatePartnerUsers = new GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers();
     
        Test.startTest();
        ID HistoricalAccountCaseBOBBatchid = Database.executeBatch(CreatePartnerUsers);
        Test.stopTest();        
  }    
 }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In the class `GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers`, because you have defined a constructor with single parameter, you will need to define the default constructor explicitly which you are calling in this line of your test class OR use the constructor with parameter which you have defined.
`GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers CreatePartnerUsers = new GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers();`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the constructor you have defined is expecting `Set<Id> contactsList`:

```
global GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers(Set<Id> contactsList){
     System.debug('Contacts List : ' +contactsList);
      listOfContacts= contactsList;
      query = 'select id, Email,ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c, phone, FirstName, LastName, AccountId,Account.Name, MailingStateCode, Agent_Code__c,vlocity_ins__Type__c from contact where id in :listOfContacts AND ARV_Agent_Portal_User_Id__c != Null AND AccountId != Null';
   }
```

However in your test class you are not passing anything to the constructor when you make an instance of the class:

```
GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers CreatePartnerUsers = new GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers();
```

So in response the error you are getting `Constructor not defined: [GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers].<Constructor>()` is simply notifying you that the compiler cannot find a constructor with no parameter. You need to pass a set of ids to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your batch class uses parameterized constructor that you are using in start method for query filter.

And you are already creating the contact data in the list: `lisOfcntcts`, you can use that list to convert to set and pass that to the constructor while creating the instance of the class. Pseudo code:

```java
GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers CreatePartnerUsers = 
    new GA_AP_CreatePartnerUsers(new Set<Id>(lisOfcntcts));
ID HistoricalAccountCaseBOBBatchid = Database.executeBatch(CreatePartnerUsers);
```